# class_weight attribute of DecisionTreeClassifier having no effect on confusion matrix, recall

Tags: python, decision-tree, imbalanced-data

I am preparing a demonstration of cost sensitive classification for a lecture and am puzzled as to why the class_weight='balanced' attribute of scikit-learn's DecisionTreeClassifier seems to be having no effect at all.

The dataset has 4521 instances, with 4000 'no' values and 521 'yes' values. I am using a 70/30 train/test split, with this code for building and fitting the model:

```
clf = DecisionTreeClassifier(criterion='entropy',random_state=42,class_weight='balanced')
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

I have also tried setting specific weights for the class attribute values.

A typical confusion matrix without balancing is:

```
[[1076  109]
 [ 105   67]]
```

A typical confusion matrix *with* balancing is:

```
[[1108   77]
 [ 112   60]]
```

No only does the balancing seem to have no effect, but in these cases, allowing for random selection of test cases, recall for "yes" got even worse.  I feel like there is something very simple and obvious that I am missing.  Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Since your problem is a binary classification, evaluate the model performance (both the standard decision tree and weighted decision tree) using ROC AUC.

The weighted decision tree is expected to perform better even if it is slight.

> It is possible that better performance can be achieved with a different class weighting, and this too will depend on the choice of performance metric used to evaluate the model [[1]](https://machinelearningmastery.com/cost-sensitive-decision-trees-for-imbalanced-classification/).

You can use Grid Search to find a range of different class weightings for the weighted decision tree and discover which results in the best ROC AUC score [[1]](https://machinelearningmastery.com/cost-sensitive-decision-trees-for-imbalanced-classification/).

For further reading and practice on Cost-Sensitive models, please check this [link](https://machinelearningmastery.com/cost-sensitive-decision-trees-for-imbalanced-classification/).

[1] [Cost-Sensitive Decision Trees for Imbalanced Classification](https://machinelearningmastery.com/cost-sensitive-decision-trees-for-imbalanced-classification/).